# ViewResult returns no data

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-2, nerddinner, viewresult

I am using the pattern from NerdDinner. I call Index() in my test Method and I the ViewREsult I get back has no data. So the variable **data** ends up being null.

However, I know that there is data there. Because I can go to the watch window and expand the variable **result** and expand **viewData->Model->ResultsView** then I see the "expanding will result view will enumerate the IEnumerable"  When I expand it, the data exists.

Any idea why the data comes back null unless I expand?

thanks
Jas

```
   [TestMethod]
    public void Index__Should_Return_1_or_More_lessons()
    {
        var controller = new LessonController(new FakeLessonRepository());

        var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        var data = result.ViewData.Model as IList<Lesson>;
        Assert.IsTrue(data.Count > 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of [Lazy Loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) in Linq or EF (depending on what you're using) The queries are only executed when needed. You can force it to be executed by calling a finalizer like ToList() or ToArray() or something similar.

Comment: hmm not sure how to get to the ToArray or ToList methods on ViewResult... Any ideas?

Comment: `var data = ((IList<Lesson>)result.ViewData.Model).ToList();` should probably work just fine

Comment: Thanks! 
var data = ((EnumerableQuery<Lesson>)result.ViewData.Model).ToList(); 

did the trick.